# 'Isset' should avoid the execution of the code

Tags: php, html, isset

I made many searchs about my problem but i'm finally asking you .. so thanks you to read :) !

There is my code :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['clearbutton'])){
  $myfile = fopen('letxt.txt', 'w') or die('Unable to open file!');
  ftruncate($myfile, 0);
  fclose($myfile);
  echo "c'est trunqué!"; // TEST
  var_dump(isset($_POST['okbutton']));
  var_dump(isset($_POST['clearbutton']));
}

if(empty($_POST['pseudo']) || empty($_POST['msg']) && isset($_POST['okbutton'])){

  echo "Tu n'as pas rempli le pseudo ou le msg !";
  var_dump(isset($_POST['okbutton'])); // TEST
  var_dump(isset($_POST['clearbutton'])); // TEST

}
elseif(!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['msg'])){
  $myfile = fopen('letxt.txt', 'a+') or die ("Unable to open file!");
  $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
  $msg = $_POST['msg'];
  fwrite($myfile, $pseudo);
  fwrite($myfile, ' : ');
  fwrite($myfile, $msg);
  fwrite($myfile, ' <br>');
  fclose($myfile);
}

$myfile = fopen('letxt.txt', 'r') or die("Unable to open file!");
if(filesize('letxt.txt') > 0){
echo fread($myfile, filesize('letxt.txt'));
fclose($myfile);
}
else
  echo "..";

?><!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="pseudo" placeholder="Entrez votre pseudo..">
    <input type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Entrez votre message..">
    <button type="submit" name="okbutton">Envoyer</button>
    </form>

    <form name="form2" method="POST" action="#">
    <button type="submit" name="clearbutton">Clear Chat</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

So everything works ( if you have ideas to make this code better, or easier, i'll take! i'm a student. ) apart the fact that if i use the `clearbutton`, it also enter in the second condition and so tell  me "tu n'as pas rempli le pseudo ou le msg!" and the two var_dumps.

How can i avoid it ? If i press `clearbutton`, only the first `if` should be executed right ? Cause the `var_dump`'s tell me that `okbutton` is false when i press `clearbutton`

Thanks you for your answers ! :D

Comment: Why not use `die()` to finish the execution?

Comment: Your second `if` needs brackets round the `||` part or the results may not be what you expect.

Comment: @NicoHaase where and what for ? Thanks you !

Comment: @NigelRen Oh yes it was that .. thanks you so much !
So without the brackets it can be understand " (first variable) || (second && third variable) " is that it ?
And now it's " (first variable || second ) && third " yes ??

Comment: Exactly that. The [PHP Operator Precedence Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) tells us that `&&` binds stronger than `||` does.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

`isset` checks if variable with given array key exist. If yes it will get into `if`. But the code will be executed futher.

Your next if checks 2 `or` conditions.
`empty($_POST['pseudo'])`
and
`empty($_POST['msg']) && isset($_POST['okbutton']`.
If any of those is `true` it will get into this `if` aswell.

If you want to execute those `if` separately it should looks like follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['clearbutton'])) { // first check, if false go futher, if true execute only this one
  $myfile = fopen('letxt.txt', 'w') or die('Unable to open file!');
  ftruncate($myfile, 0);
  fclose($myfile);
  echo "c'est trunqué!"; // TEST
  var_dump(isset($_POST['okbutton']));
  var_dump(isset($_POST['clearbutton']));
} elseif (empty($_POST['pseudo']) || empty($_POST['msg']) && isset($_POST['okbutton'])) { // second check if first is false
  echo "Tu n'as pas rempli le pseudo ou le msg !";
  var_dump(isset($_POST['okbutton'])); // TEST
  var_dump(isset($_POST['clearbutton'])); // TEST
} elseif (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['msg'])) { // third check if first and second are false
  $myfile = fopen('letxt.txt', 'a+') or die ("Unable to open file!");
  $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
  $msg = $_POST['msg'];
  fwrite($myfile, $pseudo);
  fwrite($myfile, ' : ');
  fwrite($myfile, $msg);
  fwrite($myfile, ' <br>');
  fclose($myfile);
}

// code below will be executed anyway, it doesn't matter what happens above (except die)

$myfile = fopen('letxt.txt', 'r') or die("Unable to open file!"); 

if (filesize('letxt.txt') > 0) {
  echo fread($myfile, filesize('letxt.txt'));
  fclose($myfile);
} else {
  echo "..";
}

// (...)
```

Comment: Finally if i just add some brackets around the `or` condition, it works perfectly ! I prefer to have two `if` seperate, i think it looks better overviewed !
Thanks you for your answer ! :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;) You can always accept / upvote my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
if(empty($_POST['pseudo']) || empty($_POST['msg']) && isset($_POST['okbutton'])){
```

Observations:

- this will be possibly evaluated even if the first `if` was true; if you want to avoid even considering this if the first `if` was true, then use `elseif`
- PHP evaluates your logical operators here from left to right, so the condition above is equivalent to `(empty($_POST['pseudo']) || empty($_POST['msg'])) && isset($_POST['okbutton'])`

In general it's a bad idea to vary disjunctive and conjunctive expressions in your criteria on the same level. It's much better to convert it into [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) or [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), you can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in order to normalize your criteria.